# Error calling C++ function from R - library loads, but function is not on the table

Tags: c++, r, dll

Here is the C code:

```
// a.cpp
void double_me(int* x) {
  // takes a numeric input and doubles it
  *x = *x + *x;
}
```

I compile the code with

```
>R CMD SHLIB a.cpp
```

After that i run R and type following commands:

```
 dinfo <- dyn.load("a.so")
 .C("double_me",x=2)
```

This end with error: "double_me" is not on the list.

Now the question:
dyn.load works fine, dinfo contains:

> DLL name: a Filename: /Users/myusername/a.so Dynamic lookup: TRUE

But the function is not on the table:

> is.loaded("double_me") 
>    [1] FALSE

How could it happen? This happens on macOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using `a.cpp`; C++ function names are "mangled" by the compiler. You can use your same code with the filename `a.c`, compiling it just as you did, and get the following from R:

```
> dinfo <- dyn.load("a.so")
>  .C("double_me",x=2)
$x
[1] 2
```

Or, alternatively, you can add this line to the top of `a.cpp`:

```
extern "C" void double_me(int* x);
```

and get the following from R:

```
> dinfo <- dyn.load("a.so")
>  .C("double_me",x=2)
$x
[1] 2
```

#### Update: Why was the result above 2?

If you do not coerce the argument to the proper type, a copy may be made, such that your original value is not altered; if we coerce the value to be an integer as we should when using `.C()`, we get the expected result:

```
> dyn.load("a.so")
> .C("double_me", x = as.integer(2))
$x
[1] 4
```

Comment: $x --> [1] 4 (typo?)

Comment: @AlexanderSobolev Not quite; I've add some info to explain